# QML ERROR :invalid property name minX (M16)

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qqmllistproperty

i Am using Qt 5.12.8 , i have imported

```
import QtQml.Models 2.2 
import QtQuick 2.7 
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2 
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
```

but i get this error :invalid property name minX (M16) . Can some one guide me what is my mistake!!

```
NewWindow {
    id: newWindow
    visible: !privateVars.isLoading && !privateVars.isEditing
    x: (maxX-minX)/2
    y: (maxY-minY)/2
    minX: -parent.x        //ERROR invalid property name minX (M16)
    maxX: monitor.width - width - parent.x - additionalToolbarRightMargin -25 //ERROR invalid property name maxX (M16)
    minY: -parent.y    //ERROR invalid property name minY (M16)
    maxY: monitor.height - height -parent.y  //ERROR invalid property name maxY (M16)
    onLoadClicked: privateVars.isLoading = true
    //selectedMissionInstance: loadMissionWindow.selectedMissionInstance
    onNewClicked:
    {
        //Create new mission in missionmodel and go to edit view
        missionPlanningModel.newMissionClicked()
        privateVars.isEditing = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is NewWindow? It must not have a minX property. You can add one if you want it.

Comment: I have same problem ALWAYS whenever I `import QtQml.StateMachine 1.15 as DSM` on random properties of `State` and `DSM.State`. Also I have already same problem in `title` property of the `ApplicationWindow`. It seems that this problem lives for a long time and occurs randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to make a variables minX/minY/etc for NewWindow, not to set a value for existing ones.
If that's so you should declare it. Like that:

```
NewWindow {
    id: newWindow
    visible: !privateVars.isLoading && !privateVars.isEditing
    x: (maxX-minX)/2
    y: (maxY-minY)/2
    property int minX: -parent.x     //Now it's not firing an error
    property int maxX: monitor.width - width - parent.x - additionalToolbarRightMargin -25 
    property int minY: -parent.y   
    property int maxY: monitor.height - height -parent.y maxY (M16)
    onLoadClicked: privateVars.isLoading = true
    //selectedMissionInstance: loadMissionWindow.selectedMissionInstance
    onNewClicked:
    {
        //Create new mission in missionmodel and go to edit view
        missionPlanningModel.newMissionClicked()
        privateVars.isEditing = true
    }
}
```